# How to make awk works in perl?

Tags: perl, ssh, awk, command

In my perl scripts, this code:

```
system("ssh -q ullink\@130.45.56.217 \"echo 1 2|awk '{print \$2}'\"");
```

The awk part just doesn't work! the expect result is "1", but now it's "1 2" I just can't figure out how to make it work?

Comment: The reason I doing awk on remote host is to analyze log file, I need to do grep on the log and generate output file on remote host, then I can just copy the output file to local instead of huge log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you run `awk` on the remote host, or at all?

```
system(qq(ssh -q $UL_SERVER_LOGIN\@$UL_SERVER echo 1 2 | awk '{print $2}'));
```

Or even better

```
print ((split (/\s+/,qx(ssh -q $UL_SERVER_LOGIN\@$UL_SERVER echo 1 2)))[1]);
```

The concrete problem with your script is that the dollar sign requires a lot more escapes: it gets eaten by the remote shell; but if you escape it from the remote shell with a backslash, the backslash needs to be escaped from Perl, etc etc.  It's a lot simpler if you use single quotes where you can.

```
system("ssh -q $UL_SERVER_LOGIN\@$UL_SERVER " .
    '"echo 1 2 | awk \'{ print \$2 }\'"');
```

Comment: Hi, tripleee, Thank you very much for reply. The reason I run awk on the remote host is to analyze log file. I have tried your code, but it's doesn't works, would you mind help again?

Comment: The `awk` part of the script can run on the local host just fine, the only part which needs to run remotely is `ifconfig`.  Anyway, updated my answer; hope this helps.  My system's `ifconfig` output does not contain `broadcast` anywhere so I'm not sure what I should expect to see there.  If you still have trouble, maybe you can provide sample input and output.

Comment: The log file is from production and it's huge in size, I am not sure if we can capture it by $if, would it possibility to cause memory issue or some thing else?

Answer (score 2):

`awk`, whether you intend to run it on the remote host or locally, is producing output that isn't going anywhere.  `system()` does not give you the output of the command you run, only the return status.

*Update: yes, a command run by system can still print to STDOUT, though.*

You need backquotes instead:

```
 my @output = `command here`;
 print @output;
```

Also, keep in mind that Perl can do pretty much anything `awk` can.  I would prefer to do as much processing as possible in Perl, and keep the external system commands to a minimum.   But this depends on what you are doing and is a personal preference to some extent.

Comment: `system` does print the generated output to stdout if you don't do something to prevent or capture it, so that part was actually fine.

Comment: yes, you are right. The reason I doing this is to analyze log file, I need to do grep on the log and generate output file on remote host, then I can just copy the output file to local instead of huge log files. Thanks for reply.